Prove That $f$ is Continuous With Respect to a Metric.
Suppose that $X \neq  \emptyset$ is a set and we have a metric $d: X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
If there exists a function $f: X \rightarrow X$ such that for every given $x$, and every $y \in X$, $d(x,f(x)) \leq d(x,f(y))$. Then prove that $f$ is continuous concerning the metric.
MY ATTEMPT: If the given $\epsilon$ is greater than $2d(x,f(x))$, then continuity would be straightforward by setting $\delta \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} - d(x,f(x))$, but I do not know how to deal with the other condition. However, in Euclidean Plane, I think it is true.
Thank you for your time.

Here's a hint: what would happen if we considered $X=[0,1]$ with the Euclidean metric and the function
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0,&x\leq 0.5\\1,&x>0.5\end{cases}\,\,\,\,?$$
Can you show that this is a counterexample to your claim?
